# command 'chatgpt.updateAPIkey' not found

Tags: vscode-extensions, chatgpt-api

I have added chtgpt extension to my vscode. after I uninstall it `cmd+v` shows **command 'chatgpt.updateAPIkey' not found**

Answer (score 0):

In mac:

navigate to below path

```
cd $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/
```

then open  `keybindings.json`

```
nano keybindings.json
```

remove json object which related to your `cmd (cmd+v)`.

save the update file by using below command

```
ctrl+o
```

exit the nano editor by using

```
ctrl+x
```